# Indexing across a mount point in windows

Tags: windows-7, search, filesystems, mount

I have a new windows 7 computer. The first thing I did was in stall a 2nd hard drive and mount it at C:/Users/me this seems to work just fine, except one issue.

Search does not find and file there, and the indexing service will not index it.

I think the latter is the cause of the former. Is there a to tell the indexer to look past the mount point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After much searching, I found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260207

It explains that drives mounted to folders are not indexed BY DESIGN.

It does not explain what kind of brain dead design this is, or what the reasons are.

Answer (score 2):

They explain  a bit more about this "issue" **[here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdesktopsearchhelp/thread/b42929b5-8996-4f11-bf3d-df26867b8e27/)**:

> Monitoring the [USN change journal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USN_Journal) is
>   new to WS 3.0. The benefit is that we
>   can use the journal change log to
>   determine file changes without
>   rescanning the files on the drive,
>   even if the search service is not
>   running.

In the thread, they give a link to a [**Windows Search add-in**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=F7E981D9-5A3B-4872-A07E-220761E27283&displaylang=en) which may work with Windows 7, but only for the 32-bit versioon so I cannot confirm it.

> - Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1; Windows Vista; Windows XP Service Pack 2
>
>   **Note x64 bit installations are not supported**
>
>   - Windows Desktop Search 03.00.0000.XXXX or later versions
>   - Windows Search 04.00.6001.XXXXX

I'm not sure which version of Windows Search is included in Windows 7 though. The [Indexer Gadget](http://gallery.live.com/liveItemDetail.aspx?li=45c441a6-edbc-454d-9262-d264728d6a3a&bt=1&pl=1) returns "*Windows Search version 6.1.7600.16385*" but that's the version of Windows 7. Maybe Windows Search doesn't have a separate version number anymore?

Comment: I have 64 bit. This helps a little.

Comment: This got me on the right path. the short term solution was to give the drive a letter as well as a mountpoint. the real solution is to not mount the drive, but use libraries to point to the files.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue on Windows 7 64bit. What I found is that if you (through Explorer) go to the folder to which the drive is mounted to, and then go into a subfolder, and the type something in the search textbox in the upper right corner, **you will get a popup asking you whether you want to index this “unindexed” folder**. If you click yes, the indexing service will index the folder.

Now I have no idea how to remove this location from the index as it doesn’t show up in the “Indexed locations” window. But the files are indexed, no doubt! EDIT: It seems that after the folder is deleted or unmounted, one can see the paths in “Indexed locations” window as unavailable.

One could tweak the registry and add mountpoints manually: see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/235799/exclude-directories-from-windows-search-by-wildcard)

I also find thet my mount point is correctly registered here:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Search\UsnNotifier\Windows\Volumes`

Comment: I couldn't get the popup, but regedit seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check in "Indexing options", "Modify"? From there you can select drives to be indexed.

Comment: I have been all over the indexing options, before I came here. The drive does not have a letter and does not appear in that list. It's mounted rather then lettered

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and was recommended to install Windows Desktop Search Addin for Networks, - works well for me now.
 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=f7e981d9-5a3b-4872-a07e-220761e27283

Comment: it's not available for 64-bit