# using junctions and moving the Recycle Bin to the right partition

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, user-profiles, recycle-bin, junction

I have got two partitions on a PC running Windows XP:
C:  system partition
D:  data partition

Usually every user has got his user profile on

```
C:\Documents and Settings\<user>
```

But I have moved the user profiles to the D: partition and linked them to the old locations using the junction tool from sysinternals:

```
D:\<user>
junction "D:\<user>" "C:\Documents and Settings\<user>"
```

Everything works great, but the only annoying thing is the Recycle Bin:
When a user deletes a file (which physically is located somewhere in D:\user), the file is moved to the Recycle Bin on the C: drive, which actually makes sense because Windows still thinks that it is somewhere in "C:\Documents and Settings\user". But this means that deleting files can take very long time.
So how can I tell Windows to use the Recycler on the D: partition instead?

I hope that you can understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Recycle Bin is not possible.

Plus there are some unfavorable consequences to performance to moving the Recycling bin to another drive.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (on Win10): SSD system drive, HDD data drive, junctions worked, deleting *to* the recycle bin was no problem, but **restoring** stuff from the recycle bin resulted in a copy operation when deletion was triggered from inside the symlinked path (e.g. `C:\Users\me\junction-to-d\foo`).

This problem can be circumvented by going into the `Disk Management Console`, removing the drive letter (`D:\`) and adding a mount point (e.g. `C:\data`).  Just adding a mount point is not enough, the partition is not allowed to have a drive letter at all.

Why this happens: The recycle bin view has a column `Original Location` and also knows where the file is really located (drive letter).  If the drive letter and `Original Location` are different (e.g. because a file was deleted from inside a symlink/junction), the restore operation will perform a copy operation.  If a partition is only accessed via a mount point on the system drive, there is no conflict and the usual quick restore is performed.

TL;DR: Completely abandoning `D:\` for `C:\d-drive` solves the problem and has the additional benefit of making Windows slightly more Unix-y by not having to switch drive letters in the console and such.

Edit: And that's why we can't have nice things... no file indexing support for anything without a drive letter. [Indexing across a mount point in windows](https://superuser.com/questions/72534/indexing-across-a-mount-point-in-windows)