# How can I make a folder and its content on a removable drive a permanent exception to being added to Recent files?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Windows 10 v1903

I like using Recent Files when you render something it's handy for a quick drag and drop into another app. But there are folders I want to prevent its content from ending up in Recent Files.

What setting must I assign to that folder to prevent its content from being added to Recent Files yet keep recent files working for other folders?

[EDIT] This does not solve my problem:
[Exclude folders from recent files](https://superuser.com/questions/970425/exclude-folders-from-recent-files)

I don't want 1 file to not appear in Quick Access.
I don't want 1 folder to not appear in Quick Access.
I don't want to disable Quick Access.

I want to modify a folder by changing the setting of the folder so that its content doesn't appear in Recent Files. Maybe changing a folder's permission or some property that keeps Quick Access from adding the files in it?

Comment: What OS is in question?

Comment: @ankii Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude folders from recent files](https://superuser.com/questions/970425/exclude-folders-from-recent-files)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude directories from Windows Search by wildcard](https://superuser.com/questions/235799/exclude-directories-from-windows-search-by-wildcard)

Comment: @ankii I don't want to exclude directories from a search.