# OneDrive on a Mounted Volume

Tags: mount, ntfs, onedrive

I am trying to create a partition to store my OneDrive files so it can be accessed on both my Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu installations.

The shared partition is formatted with NTFS and I am currently mounting it to `C:\Users\James\OneDrive`. To do so I had to firstly stop the OneDrive process (`skydrive.exe`), permanently delete the old OneDrive folder (at `C:\Users\James\OneDrive`), re-create the OneDrive folder and finally mount the partition through Disk Management. However, when I start OneDrive again it stays open for a bit while the tool tip says `Getting your file list`, finds 7 (and always 7) files (I have way more than that), then crashes.

So my question is, is there anyway to use OneDrive on a Mounted Volume without it crashing?

I think this issue might have something to do with Mounted Volumes not being indexed in Windows: [support.microsoft.com/kb/260207](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260207). So, could there be any validity to manually editing the registry as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/595976/402259)?

Thanks!

**Other Stuff:**

OneDrive Properties: 
[image]

OneDrive Sync Progress on crash:
[image]

OneDrive log: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C604C49A28DD31D!52486&authkey=!ANodbITl3MIcWpo&ithint=file%2ctxt.

Comment: A potential solution might be to see if you can create a junction from the working OneDrive folder (before you deleted it...) to your share. A junction is like a symlink but it "fakes" the location so OneDrive is none the wiser of where the data is... You may need to install a software in Windows that provides that capability, though.

Comment: Ok, so that slight improvement. I created `C:\OneDriveData` then mounted the shared partition in there. I then stopped the OneDrive process, deleted `C:\Users\James\OneDrive` and then ran `mklink /J "C:\Users\James\OneDrive" "C:\OneDriveData"` in an elevated command prompt. Upon starting OneDrive again it found all my files (more than 7!), then crashed. Every subsequent time I restart OneDrive after the initial run reverts to finding only 7 files. Logs: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C604C49A28DD31D!52487&authkey=!AIGr1eTL91LPnXU&ithint=file%2ctxt.

Comment: You might have to delete the c:\users\james\onedrive folder -> repair onedrive so it recreates the folder -> go offline so it doesn't sync -> create the junction (mklink) -> go back online to sync -> see what happens. I'm wondering if it's a permissions problem because you deleted the folder. Have you checked both folder permissions and who owns the onedrive folder that onedrive originally created?

Comment: So following those instructions I checked the permissions of the folder created by the OneDrive process when it found no folder (before creating the symlink). SYSTEM, my user and Administrators all have full access except Special Permissions. The instructions fail, however, when creating the symbolic link as the folder (`C:\Users\James\OneDrive`) already exists: `Cannot create a file when that file already exists`. So instead I had to delete the folder then create the link. After creating the link the permissions where the same as the folder created by the OneDrive process. No change though.